# how to use twig body onload.. windows.load doesnot work

Tags: google-maps, symfony, twig

How to use "onload()" function in twig. I tried using windows.load and $(document).ready(function(){ ****** }) but the map does not to load. I got no errors using firebug

Here is the code with both  and windows.load

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f7d6954f172dbf67a6ac

Comment: If you put a console.log inside, is it been shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for use without the jQuery library i recommand:

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert('script works');
};
```

The best option using Twig is to using the javascript block:

```
...
{% block javascript %}

    window.onload = function() {
        alert('script works');
    };

{% endblock %}
```

The javascript block will be inserted just before the /body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        /*ALL YOUR CODE*/

    });
</script>
```